# Upgraded to Xcode 6 Beta 7 and now getting: the file info.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting "the file info.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file" when I build our SDK's sample app.  I looked in the Build Settings and the path to the Info.plist file is as it should be.  The only thing that is new is that I've installed Beta 7.

If you look at the repo at: ([Swift SDK Sample App](https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/Swift-Sample-App)), you'll see the file there.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the expanded error messages the first item shows that it is looking for the plist file in:

```
.../Swift-Sample-App-master/Swift-Sample-App/Swift-Sample-App/SWXMLHash/Info.pl‌​ist
```

It looks like you re-organized the files and did not change the location of the Build Settings.
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Ended up it was thinking the structure old SDK was there, not the new one.